# I want to add an element to an array at random postion using a loop

Tags: php

I want to add an element to an array at random postion using a loop

I have a fixed ranks like the following

```
$ranks=array("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
```

And I have a random rank position according to a chain,

```
$agent_ranks=array("10","6","2","1");
```

**which are missing indices**

I have calculated the difference between the arrays

```
$arr_diff=array("9","8","7","5","4","3");
```

Now I want a dynamic array as a result:

```
$arr_diff_new=array("0","9","8","7","0","5","4","3","0","0");
```

How can I add `value="0"` at the missing indices?

Comment: create a new array, and iterating through the ranks, add to it 0 or the number depending if the value exists in missing index

Comment: btw: What's _random_ about the positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `in_array` and for loop:

```
$ranks=array("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
$agent_ranks=array("10","6","2","1");

for($i=0;$i < count($ranks); $i++){
    if(in_array($ranks[$i], $agent_ranks)){
        $newarray[$i] = 0;
    }else{
        $newarray[$i] = $ranks[$i];
    }
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: @VivekSrivastava: If it's work then give upvote and mark as answer, So other user trust in mark answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$ranks=array("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
$agent_ranks= array_flip( array("10","6","2","1") );

foreach( $ranks as $k=>$v ) {
    if ( isset($agent_ranks[$v]) ) {
        $ranks[$k] = 0;
    }
}

var_export($ranks);
```

prints

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => '9',
  2 => '8',
  3 => '7',
  4 => 0,
  5 => '5',
  6 => '4',
  7 => '3',
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
)
```

see also: [<kbd>`array_flip`</kbd>](http://docs.php.net/array_flip)

Comment: No need to use an extra function like as `array_flip`

Comment: What's more "extra" about array_flip than in_array? btw: No _need_ to use foreach, either. It's just simple and convinient. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `in_array` in if clause to check if rank is int `$agent_ranks` and then push 0 or old rank value to new array

```
$arr_diff_new = array();
foreach($ranks as $rank){
    array_push($arr_diff_new,(in_array($rank,$agent_ranks))?0:$rank);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array function array_map,

```
<?php
$array1=array("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
print_r(array_map('filter',$array1));
function filter($a){
 $array2=array("9","8","7","5","4","3");
 if(in_array($a,$array2)){
    return $a;
 }else{
    return 0;
 }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `in_array` with `foreach` loop like as

```
$ranks=array("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
$agent_ranks=array("10","6","2","1");
$result = array();
foreach($ranks as $key => $value){
    $result[] = in_array($value,$agent_ranks) ? 0 : $value;
}
print_r($result);
```